# Restrict City Labels in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

This may be an easy one but I couldn't find an answer anywhere.  Is there a way to only show cities of a certain size no matter what zoom level that anyone knows of?  This would be for Google Maps.  I would like to do something like:

```
if (zoomLevel < X && city.size < Y)
   city.showlabel = false;
```

All I have come up with are ways to restrict your search options but nothing on the actual map display itself.  Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You can hide certain elements of the map (including city label) using styled maps, but you would have to do it manually for each city size you want to restrict; you cannot write a piece of code programatically and have it apply for every subsequent size you specify later.  You can read more about map styling below:

https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/customizing/styling-the-base-map#hiding_features
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling

You set the label's visibility to "off" to hide it.